# Theoretical Max G forces on Shuttle Launch?

Tags: space-shuttle, ssme, acceleration

Reading this question [Why are rocket engines operating above 100% often considered nominal?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5744/why-are-rocket-engines-operating-above-100-often-considered-nominal) leads me to a question about throttling back the SSMEs in the later stages of a Shuttle Launch to limit G forces on the astronauts.  If the SSMEs were not throttled back, what would have been the anticipated G Forces on the astronauts at the end of the main SSME burn time?

Comment: The 3 g limit during the launch phase was in place for payload and payload berthing reasons, not to limit the forces on the crew.

Comment: @Digger, Upon additional digging, I came across the following answer which backs up your assertion that the G limit was more for payload than crew accommodation, as earlier launches had significantly higher G loadings during launch to space.  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/7829/launch-accelerations-values-history

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stealing the mass-at-MECO number from this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/264/energy-cost-of-bringing-the-space-shuttle-external-tank-to-orbit), and using the 104.5% thrust numbers for 3 SSMEs from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_main_engine), I get

(3 x (490,000) lbf / 308650 lbm ) = **~ 4.75 g's**

*Sanity check*

*(3 x (.65 x 490,000) lbf / 308650 lbm ) = ~ 3.1 g's*

*Using the approximate 65% power level at shutdown, assuming that the thrust varies linearly with throttle percent (and ignoring that they normally only throttled to 67%) gives the expected approximate 3 g's*

Info on nominal throttle settings in the answer to this question: [Which STS mission raised the normal engine throttle above 100%, and what change to the SSME made that possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16971/which-sts-mission-raised-the-normal-engine-throttle-above-100-and-what-change)